# Creating a new Blazor project for components and pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor

I am creating a Blazor WASM project and would like to separate my Blazor components and pages from the hosting model.

This would make it easy to change hosting model to for example a Server based application, where I just would need to create a new project and reference my components and pages library.
It would also allow me to separate my components and pages library from specific implementations (services or data models) by using interfaces and DI. Only the hosting project would need to know my implementation details.

The issue is that I cannot get it to work properly with visual studio. I have tried to create a .NET Standard 2.1 project for my components/pages but then I cannot create new razer components. Do I need to configure the project in some way? How should I make my shared components/pages library?

Answer (score 5):

You need to select a Razor Class Library template:

[image: New project template]

It will contain a wwwroot directory where you can put your images, css or other static web resources. You can also use Library Manager (libman.json) if you add the json.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that but then I ticked the checkbox "Support Pages and Views", which created a template that I thought looked a bit odd.